# Iterator: One past the last element in Java

Tags: java, iterator

Like in C++, we have end() where the iterator ends up at the position one past the last element, is it true for Java iterator has well?

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String color = iterator.next();
}
```

E.g. In C++, we have:

```
Blue Green Purple
  ^    ^     ^    ^
begin            end
```

How would I have to draw the above illustration in Java thinking/terminology?

Comment: RTFM -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--

Comment: `Iterator` is an interface. Any implementation has to provide `next()` and `hasNext()`. Doesn't have to be done in any particular way.

Comment: The `Iterator` in Java is a bit like a pointer, except that doesn't point to the "current" element (like `*it` does in C++), it points to *just before* the next element. So there's a slight mismatch between the C++ and Java models.

Comment: @AndyTurner: If it points to just before the current element then wouldn't it move to one past the last element upon calling next? E.g. `^ Blue ^ Green ^ Purple ^`.

Comment: Still, interesting question. I always like it to *question* things that seem to be cast in stone. Gives interesting food for thought very often.

Comment: Beyond that: I tried to make your question "easier to understand". Please check; and revert in case disapprove my wording.

Comment: @GhostCat it's not set in stone, it's mere convention. There's no obvious reason why it wasn't done in a C++-y way in the first place (`Iterator` could have had `hasCurrent()`, `current()` and `next()` methods), it just wasn't. Perhaps it was felt to be neater to have 2 methods in the interface instead of 3. In any case, you aren't stopped from doing it like that, it's just that you're swimming against the tide of convention, and so have to do more yourself.

Comment: @AndyTurner Please note I said *seem*. I do understand that nothing is really cast into stone.

Comment: @AndyTurner, `Iterator` is designed as-if it points somewhere between elements, with `next()` (and `previous()`) passing over an element and returning it, so if we are strict to definition, there can't be a `current()` element. However, it's not particularly hard to make something like `MemorizingIterator` which can also act as a container to element it last seen by "passing over" it. If we define a `Box<T> {T get(); boolean isPresent();}`, then that class is-a `Iterator<T>&Box<T>`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov like I said: "it points to *just before* the next element".

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes, and if it behaves like that, it can't have `current()` - only `next()` or `previous()`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov "Iterator **could have had**" those methods. It doesn't, because that's not how it was designed, instead it has the methods it has, and it points to just before the next value.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `Iterator` is an *interface* meaning that there has to be a concrete class implementing the methods of the interface. Now that depends on the type of collection that is used. As an example, to iterate on a collection of the type List, we use a `ListIterator`.

For a `listIterator`, there is no current element that it holds. The cursor position would lie between elements, at the beginning of the collection or at the end of the last element in the list. The illustration should make it more clear.

So, when `hasNext()` returns false, you know you are at the end of the Collection (List, in our case) which throws a *`NoSuchElementException`*.

[image: Sample of a listIterator]

Answer (score 2):

There is a key difference here: in C++, you are still talking about "pointers" in the sense of "memory locations".

In C++, it makes sense to point to the "end" outside of a collection (to a certain degree; as the other answer nicely outlines).

In Java, it does not.

Because "we" don't think about collections as "one continuous place in memory". "We" think about it as ... a collection of objects. You can iterate them; and that is **all** you need to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, something is an iterator if it implements `next()` and `hasNext()`. Nothing is said about the underlying memory model. "One past the last element" is not a helpful concept.

Your C++ case example is only really pertinent to some containers, e.g. `std::vector`. A `std::list` is not modelled in the way you have it, for example. Also it's not a good idea to think of "one past the end" as being an actual memory location. That concept has crept into C++ parlance due to your being allowed to set a pointer one past the end of an array or the address of a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Java iterators implement the `java.util.Iterator<E>` interface.

When newly created an iterator is (logically) before the first element of the iterated elements. That's because `next()` will return the first element (if any).

When it is exhausted an iterator is (logically) after the last element and `hasNext()` will return `false`.

However Java doesn't in general implement value comparison semantics for iterators.

Consider:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList();
    numbers.add(7);
    numbers.add(8);

    Iterator<Integer> begin=numbers.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> iter=numbers.iterator();

    System.out.println(begin.equals(iter));
}
```

The expected output is `false`.

There's nothing against implementing `equals()` to have value semantics for some custom `Iterator` implementing `class` but the Java provided `interface` is fairly limited and there's no universal way of laying it over the top.

C++ iterators as just a richer protocol for iterators.

We can certainly implement an `EndIterator` class (see below) but it won't be much use unless there's a meaningful way to compare iterators (by say `equals()`).

The only meaningful thing an `end()` method can do is return an `Iterator` that always returns `false` to `hasNext()` and always throws an exception on calls to `next()`.

```
class EndIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return false;
    }

    public E next(){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return 123456;//Arbitrary and technically invalid...
    }

    public boolean Equals(Object other){
        if(!(other instanceof Iterator)){
            return false;
        }
        Iterator otheri=(Iterator)other;
        return otheri.hasNext()==false;
    }
}
```

Notice this doesn't really work because the Java collections haven't implemented an equality relation that two iterators are equal if they are (say) at the same point of iteration in the same container.
C++  has that and it makes `end()` meaningful but it can't be (easily) retrofitted on to Java.

Comment: I don't quite understand what iterator equality have to do with anything. Yes, java collection return new iterator on every call, and no, array list iterator's equal is reference comparison, so equals fails, but it is not expected. And i also don't see what would be richer about iterators in C++.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I've amended my answer. The question is about an `end()` method. But such a method is pretty useless unless you can make comparisons with other objects because `end()` needs to be an essentially dead object. With in the provided `Iterator` `interface` you can't really do anything with what `end()` needs to return.

Comment: `end()` is dead object in terms of just `Iterator`, but it can be unwound in case of bidirectional `ListIterator`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov There are always extensions. But within the confines of the `Iterator` 'interface` it's a dead object. My point is there are iterators that are 'past the end' but that isn't the same as the notion of a sentinel position of 'end' because Java `Iterator` and sub-interfaces don't implement `equals()` to have value semantics. The question is about comparing C++ and Java.